# find a fix value from a column around a range with each unique values of another column in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
col1      col2
 1        50000
 1        2000
 2        51000
 3        100
 3        5000
 3        50500
 4        200
 4        51500
 5        49000
```

I want to identify the values with plus minus 10 percent for each of col1 values which occurs for every col1 unique values.

the final output should look like

```
col1        col2
  1         50000
  2         51000
  3         50500
  4         51500
  5         49000
```

if other values other than the values around 50000 presents and have within plus minus 10 percent range, add those with the values around 50000

How to do it using pandas/python with most efficient way ?

Comment: So `50000` is necessary find? Or it is input value and is necessary find +-10% from `50000` ?

Comment: @jezrael it should find a value on its own which is fixed around +- 10 percent for each unique col1 value. In this case its around 50000

Comment: @N.Arunoprayoch not the maximum value, the value I need which is fix in plus minus 10 percent range form every col1 unique value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list cpmprehension for loop by all unique values of `col2`, filter by `+-10%` with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and compare if all values exist in all groups with set created by `col1`. Last filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
s = set(df['col1'])
print (s)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

a = [x for x in df['col2'].unique() 
     if set(df.loc[df['col2'].between(x - x *.1, x + x*.1), 'col1']) == s]
print (a)
[50000, 51000, 50500, 51500, 49000]

df = df[df['col2'].isin(a)]
print (df)
   col1   col2
0     1  50000
2     2  51000
5     3  50500
7     4  51500
8     5  49000
```

Comment: Thanks, This works when we have the values around 50000, if there is a another col1 value with 6 and col2 value 1000, in this case this code returns empty list. But I dont want empty list. If the values around 50000 is presents more than half times for unique col1 values just return the list and ignore those value.

Comment: @KallolSamanta - Hmmm, this was not easy, and solution `is presents more than half times for unique col1 values just return the list and ignore those value.` - not idea how implement it. Maybe the best is create new question.